# Does my android app need to use Google Play In-app Billing for in-app subscriptions?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I have a web app that works in conjunction with a locally installed desktop app.
Users have the option to upgrade to a premium membership for a monthly fee.
Both apps provide 100% of the functionality of my product(this is important for my question).
To widen my distribution I'm considering adding an android app.
Now, I know that Google generally forces android apps to use their in-app billing.
However, reading the [developer terms](https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/) I see this:

> Developers offering products within another category of app downloaded
> on Google Play must use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of
> payment, except for the following cases: Payment is solely for
> physical products
>
> **Payment is for digital content that may be consumed
> outside of the app itself (e.g. songs that can be played on other
> music players).**

It seems like the bolded part applies to my product, since

- it's not a game
- the premium membership can be consumed entirely without the android app(using my  desktop or web app)

Am I allowed to publish my android app to Google Play using my own payment processor or will google crack down on me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app store policies are off topic

Answer (score 3):

You should be fine.

As long as the purchase isn't for something that can only be used inside the app, you're good. Since your purchase option applies across all platforms, you fall under that exception.

Of course, Google being Google, they could take down your app. However, you should just need to appeal that decision and talk to an actual person to get it sorted out.

Comment: Why Google is forcing to shift to their payment mechanisms and apply burden of 30% charges.